# Read specific portion of file text, and then add them in array

Tags: java, arrays, file

I have a file text called messages.txt as following:

```
6107586533  44335557075557777
4848675309  53366 6699044404666804448
6107584096  94466602777330999666887770223377778077778 883 336687777
```

First column represents the numbers of recipient and second column represents the digit-coded message(and I will use a decoder method to decode the second column digits, which I have already created).I used the following method to read the file text:

```
public void readMessagesFromFile() throws Exception{
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("messages.txt"));
 String str;

 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
 while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
     list.add(str);
 }

 String[] stringArr = list.toArray(new String[3]);
 for (String x: stringArr) {
     System.out.print(x);
}
}
```

However, it stores everything(as it should be) like the following:

```
6107586533  443355570755577774848675309 53366 66990444046668044486107584096 94466602777330999666887770223377778077778 883 336687777
```

How can I read and store only the following portion:

```
    44335557075557777
    53366 6699044404666804448
    94466602777330999666887770223377778077778 883 336687777
```

I want to read and store as in lines,i.e. each row in the second column will be assigned to each index of the array), just want to exclude the first column when I store the second column.

Comment: Have you looked at `String#split()`?  Also, by _"second column"_ do you really mean _"everything except the first space-delimited token"_?

Comment: First of all, some lines contain more than 2 columns (supposing a single or multiplespace is considered a separator). After that, you read the lines without splitting each of them into its parts

Comment: I have already applied the split method in my decoder method,which will decode each digit piece by piece by piece.But I need to first read the second column, then I will apply the decoder method.

Comment: `java.util.Scanner` might be easier to use than `BufferedReader`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will split the line and keep everything after the first token

```
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
 while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
     String[] temp = str.trim().split("\\s+",2);
     list.add(temp[1]);
 }
```

The call to `trim` is in case there are leading blanks.

As to the conversion to an array your code, you don't need it, you can iterate over the list.

```
 for (String s : list)
 {
     System.out.println(s);
 }
```

Comment: It's giving this:4433555707555777753366 669904440466680444894466602777330999666887770223377778077778 883 336687777.It's storing second column without following the specific pattern as I mentioned.